# Click anywhere on a GridView row to enter the edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to duplicate the same functionality of the edit button using a single click anywhere in a GridView row.

The code below does this, but with a major problem: if the user clicks off of one textbox to the next, **the edit command fires again**, and the changes made to the previous textbox revert back to it's original value.

Any suggestions on how to fix this behaviour?

Or, is there a better approach to accomplishing this?

**EDIT:** This was resolved by adding a check for `row.RowState.HasFlag( DataControlRowState.Edit )`. See code below:

```
protected override void Render( System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer )
{
    foreach( GridViewRow row in gvwOrderItems.Rows )
    {
        if( row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
            row.RowState.HasFlag( DataControlRowState.Edit ) == false )
        {
            // enable click on row to enter edit mode
            row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink( gvwOrderItems, "Edit$" + row.DataItemIndex, true );
        }
    }
    base.Render( writer );
}
```

Comment: I added this code to my RowDataBound handler, and then instead of using row.DataItemIndex as the 2nd parameter, I used gv.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value I then catch the event in the RowEditing event and the e.NewEditIndex is my item's ID rather than the row index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for `row.RowState.HasFlag( DataControlRowState.Edit )`.

```
protected override void Render( System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer )
{
    foreach( GridViewRow row in gvwOrderItems.Rows )
    {
        if( row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
            row.RowState.HasFlag( DataControlRowState.Edit ) == false )
        {
            // enable click on row to enter edit mode
            row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink( gvwOrderItems, "Edit$" + row.DataItemIndex, true );
        }
    }
    base.Render( writer );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been going through a ton of sites for days where the code was incomplete or didn't work.  This is similar to what I needed, great example!

Comment: I have made the gridview row as editable on click event and then how to save after perform edit...

Comment: @jim31415 i need the same functionality on my project but i am getting the following error under hasflag it says:  Error 8 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState' does not contain a definition for 'HasFlag' and no extension method 'HasFlag' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) did you face this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this as I don't use `GridView`, but I do it with other controls.  You should be able to put hidden button in the row and call `Click` on the row via JavaScript:

```
protected override void Render( System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer )
{
    foreach( GridViewRow row in gvwOrderItems.Rows )
    {
        if( row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.ID = "whatever";
            b.CommandName = "edit";
            b.Attributes.Add("style","display:none;")
            row.Controls.Add(b);
            // enable click on row to enter edit mode
            row.Attributes.Add("onclick" ,"document.getElementById('" bla.ClientID "').click();");
        }
    }
    base.Render( writer );
}
```

Comment: I get the same behaviour. Once in the edit mode, clicking in a textbox triggers the edit command again.