# How to set gridview to edit mode on button click instead of using commandname

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi all I am having a template field as follows with an itemtemplate

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Delete">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick=lnkEdit_Click">     </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Generally instead of `Click` event we use to write `CommandName="Edit"` and on `OnRowEditing` event we will set gridview row to edit mode with the following code

```
protected void grdDemo_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdDemo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindGrid();
    }
```

Instead of this I would to set gridview row to edit mode on link button click, how can we do that any ideas please

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of other option available since you wish to ignore the commandname :)

1. [Click anywhere to activate edit mode in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262409/click-anywhere-on-a-gridview-row-to-enter-the-edit-mode)
2. [Activate Edit mode based on ID - Datakey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438116/asp-net-gridview-how-to-activate-edit-mode-based-on-id-datakey)
3. Set the EditIndex property to the appropriate row and then ReBind the GridVIew again to it's DataSource.

   ```
   protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
     GridView1.EditIndex = 1;
    }
   ```
4. Google/Bing for more..

Answer (score 0):

You can use edit item template as follows

the following is the sample aspx code

```
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblSubject"  Width="100%" Height="100%"  CommandName="Edit"   ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Subject") %>'>
  </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Subject") %>'>
       </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't want to use `commandname=edit` that's my question this I already know