# asp .net gridview search and edit

Tags: .net, gridview

I have a problem with editing row after searching. When I find my user and click button Edit in gridview it turns me first record but not in edit mode. After cliking second time on my search button I have my record in edit mode. I've tried to solve it by using GridViewRow.RowState Property regarding to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. When I was clicking Edit it does nothig but after second click I have error "Failed to load viewstate"
I have tried to solve it by adding on page EnableViewState="true", but all the time I had the same error. My BindData() method looks like this:

```
private void BindData()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string display = "SELECT * FROM User";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = display;
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

and search method looks like this:

```
 protected void DisplayUser(string strSearch)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchUsers", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchUser", strSearch);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I also tried to change method DisplayUser instead of void to DataSet but still I had the same error. 
My StoredProcedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SearchUsers
```

@SearchUser varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM [User]
    WHERE ([User].name LIKE '%' +@SearchUser + '%' OR [User].surname LIKE '%' 
    + @SearchUser + '%' OR [User].role LIKE '%' + @SearchUser + '%' OR [User].block 
    LIKE '%' +@SearchUser + '%')

My grid loos like this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="id_user" onRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" onRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" onRowDataBound="GridView1OnRowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" onRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onselectedindexchanged="GV_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LP" Visible="false" SortExpression="id_user"  HeaderStyle-Width="5px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="id_uzytkownika" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id_user")%>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" ReadOnly="true" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="surname" ReadOnly="true" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" ReadOnly="true" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="login" HeaderText="Login" SortExpression="login" ReadOnly="true" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" SortExpression="password">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LblPass" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("password")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPass" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("password")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("role") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpDwnRole" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Block" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBlock" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("block") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChckBxBlock" Text="Block" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Usuń" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Can some one give me some advices how to sole it?

RowEditing - it is now, but when I wanted to use row stte it looks like on the link at teh beginning of the question.

```
   protected void GridViewKierUzytkownik_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
     GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();

    }
```

1. I am using VS2010 nad MVC 4 C#.
2. You are talkin about edit, cancel and save buttons? I am using them to edit data, update and cancel updating. Basics operations for gridview.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are hitting the search button while the page is still in edit mode at any point in time? Also the code you provided is likely not relevant to your question. It should be more useful to see what is on your aspx page, specifically the gridview and search controls. Their code behind does not seem to be useful as you description is more indicative of an issue with the control and not the logic.

Comment: After my first hit I can see the users data but not in edit mode. After second hit I have error. My grid looks like this:

Comment: Ok more questions. 1. what version of .net are you using? 2. is there a reason for using the link buttons over CommandField (I just find this control a bit easier). 3. please add your GridView1_RowEditing function to your post. Also adding this link as I think it is related to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037103/how-to-set-gridview-to-edit-mode-on-button-click-instead-of-using-commandname