# making my gridview editable when clicked on any row, hasflag not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

As of now I have my `GridView` set up with some textboxes to insert data into the database. Then I have edit columns on the side. Well there are too many columns, so the user does not want to scroll all the way to edit a column but rather would love it if he/she could just click on one field and be able to edit that right away. I looked on stackoverflow and found this code that does exactly what I need:

```
 protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && row.RowState.HasFlag(DataControlRowState.Edit) == false)
                {
                    row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
                }
            }
            base.Render(writer);
        }
```

It is throwing an error on Has Flag. This is the error I am getting:

> Error 8   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState' does not
>   contain a definition for 'HasFlag' and no extension method 'HasFlag' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Odd - where did you get the code from?  Because by looking at the doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate(v=vs.100).aspx): it should work.

Comment: I got the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262409/click-anywhere-on-a-gridview-row-to-enter-the-edit-mode

Comment: Now I see - it should work since that is an enum and HasFlag is defined for enum types.  You can also use the code that I placed above in place of the code that reads: row.RowState.HasFlag(DataControlRowState.Edit) == false unless there is something else wrong there that I am not seeing.  With the one provision that it will only work if that one flag and only one flag is set.

Comment: when i tried with row.RowState.HasFlag(DataControlRowState.Edit) == false it doesn't auto update when i click on the next cell instead it reverts back to the previous value, also is there a way to only update one field, when i click it on a field an entire row gets selected

Comment: Are you using the standard gridview included in Visual Studio or you using a custom control from somebody else?  That is the only way that I can see that this won't work - the types could be different in a control from a different provider.  And yes, you should use the code from the original post - I can see how my suggestion might cause problems.

Comment: i am using just a standard gridview included in visual studio, im thinking of simple just freezing the insert and edit columns that the the user can click and enter edit mode then click on update and that would update the fields.

Comment: The original code should work, so where did you put the code?  You put it in the code-behind page right?

Comment: So, are we back to the original code?  That code will not update the record, so you will need some for that as well.  Also, as to your original error - the code that was in that post will work with .Net Framework 4.0, but not 3.5.  If I change my project to 3.5, then I get the error.